# PHPexcel / CI Message: Trying to get property of non-object?

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration, phpexcel

I have a problem with CodeIgniter when create report to Excel with PHPExcel. This is the message:

```
Message: Trying to get property of non-object Line 274 - Line 278
```

// query

```
$sqlcoba="SELECT a.kd_mahasiswa, a.thn_angkatan, a.nim, a.nama, a.alamat, a.no_telp, b.nama_prodi, d.kd_dosen, d.nama_dosen, a.nama_ortu, a.alamat_ortu, a.pekerjaan, a.telp_ortu, a.status, a.kd_prodi, c.kd_fakultas, c.nama_fakultas
        FROM tbl_mahasiswa a
        JOIN ref_prodi b ON b.kd_prodi = a.kd_prodi
        LEFT JOIN ref_fakultas c ON c.kd_fakultas = b.kd_fakultas
        LEFT JOIN ref_dosen d ON d.kd_dosen = a.kd_dosen
        WHERE a.kd_prodi = $fil1 and a.thn_angkatan = $fil2";
```

// array

```
$sqlmhs=$this->db->query($sqlcoba);
foreach ($sqlmhs->result_array() as $rowcoba)
           {
                $nim       = $rowcoba->nim;      // line 274
                $nama      = $rowcoba->nama;
                $alamat   = $rowcoba->alamat;
                $no_telp  = $rowcoba->no_telp;
                $status   = $rowcoba->status;   // line 278
            }
```

// PhpExcel

```
$bar=3;
$no = 0;
$no = $no+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('B'.$bar, $no)
        ->setCellValue('C'.$bar, $nim)
        ->setCellValue('D'.$bar, $nama)
        ->setCellValue('E'.$bar, $alamat)
        ->setCellValue('F'.$bar, $no_telp)
        ->setCellValue('G'.$bar, $status);
        $bar=$bar+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now a days i dont practice in CodeIgniter as such.. But I think here is mistake

Refer line number 271 and 272

```
$sqlmhs=$this->db->query($sqlcoba);
foreach ($sqlmhs->result_array() as $rowcoba)
```

on line 272, you are accessing object as array. So in foreach loop, you have to access array elements like `$rowcoba['nim']`.

Let me know if this works.
You can refer https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html of more details.

Comment: thanks .. it's true, but why that appear only one data? 
I try to run the query in SQL Yog and the results that came out a lot of data.

Comment: Can you share some link? It might be because of some where condition or loop thing!

Comment: this is on localhost.

Comment: I mean.. You said that you have tried same thing in SQL Yog. That link!

Answer (score 0):

@Kuku Your Script its true..but just out of the data. there should be a lot of data which could come out. 
apparently in the script

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('B'.$bar, $no)
        ->setCellValue('C'.$bar, $nim)
        ->setCellValue('D'.$bar, $nama)
        ->setCellValue('E'.$bar, $alamat)
        ->setCellValue('F'.$bar, $no_telp)
        ->setCellValue('G'.$bar, $status);
```

must be placed in the foreach. so..

```
$bar=3;
$no = 0;
foreach ($sqlmhs->result_array() as $rowcoba)
            {                  
                $nim    = $rowcoba['nim'];    
                $nama   = $rowcoba['nama'];
                $alamat = $rowcoba['alamat'];
                $no_telp= $rowcoba['no_telp'];
                $status = $rowcoba['status'];
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('B'.$bar, $no)
        ->setCellValue('C'.$bar, $nim)
        ->setCellValue('D'.$bar, $nama)
        ->setCellValue('E'.$bar, $alamat)
        ->setCellValue('F'.$bar, $no_telp)
        ->setCellValue('G'.$bar, $status);
        $no = $no+1;
        $bar=$bar+1;
            }
```

Thanks.